# Decrease length of underline in math

Tags: math-mode

In math I often find that single underlined letters have too long of a line. 
Here is an example: `$\beta\in[\underline{\beta},\bar{\beta}]$`

[image]

Or perhaps worse:

[image]

I can solve the too narrow bar loading some accents from the `mathxm` font of package `mathabx`, but I have not found a good way to decrease the width of e.g. `\underline{U}`.

I would appreciate a hint.

---

Here is a summary of different functions.  I have added the nunder-function, which is kind of fun.  However, it desperately needs an additional optional argument to set the division factor `\mkern\the\numexpr#1/2mu\relax` (hard-coded to two).

Two see why compare the following examples of KP-fonts (left) and CM|nunder div by 2 (middle) and CM|nunder div. by 10 (right).  On the right image `nunder` is perhaps as nice as `bunderline`.

[image: Kp-font]
[image: CM1]
[image: CM2]

`nunder` works very well KP-fonts, but performs poorly with CM with the hard-coded value of 2.  I will have two look further into two optional arguments, but my first attempt was not a success (using the blah example of TeX Faq).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\bunderline}[2][4]{\underline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}
\newcommand{\boverline}[2][4]{\overline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}
\newcommand{\nunder}[2][5]{\mathrlap{\mkern\the\numexpr#1/2mu\relax\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}#2}
\newcommand{\nunderline}[2][4]{%
  \ensuremath{\mathrlap{\mkern#1mu\underline{\phantom{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}}#2}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \label{eq:4}
  \nunderline[3]{U}\nunderline[3]{\beta}\\
  \nunderline[6]{U}\nunderline[6]{\beta}\\
  \bunderline[6]{U}\bunderline[2]{\beta}\\
  \nunder[6]{U}\nunder[2]{\beta}\\
  \nunder[3]{U}\nunder[2]{\beta}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a remark possibly a bit off-topic: your comparison of `\underline` with `\bar` is a bit misguided; replace `\bar` with `\overline` and you get something visually compatible with `\underline`. `\bar` is supposed to denote some other variable, like a statistical mean, and this is not what `\underline` is supposed to be used for. So your quite legitimate question could have been formulated rather as "is there an `\underbar`?".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the object to underline making TeX into believing it's shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bunderline}[1]{\underline{#1\mkern-4mu}\mkern4mu }

\begin{document}
$\beta\in[\bunderline{\beta},\bar{\beta}]\qquad \bunderline{U}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As remarked by Rasmus, one might also introduce an optional argument for deciding, in particular cases, the amount of shortening:

```
\newcommand{\bunderline}[2][4]{\underline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu }
```

With `\bunderline[6]{U}` one would get more shortening.

### EDIT

Every font family seems to need a particular default for the shortening and, maybe also a "front shortening". For example, this seems to work well with KPfonts:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand{\bunderline}[1]{\mkern2mu\underline{\mkern-2mu#1\mkern-4mu}\mkern4mu }
```

[image]

A package to consider is [`accents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accents) that provides `\underaccent`:

```
\underaccent{\bar}{U}
```

Here's the result (with KPfonts) of

```
$\beta\in[\underaccent{\bar}{\beta},\bar{\beta}]\qquad\underaccent{\bar}{U}$
```

[image]

Comment: A potentially nice addition is `\newcommand{\bunderline}[2][4]{\underline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu }`

Comment: @Rasmus I agree.

Comment: Do you think it would be re-center the underline ex post shortening?  The appropriate length for U might be something like `\bunderline[6]{U}`, but then, at least with KP-fonts, the line is sort of dragged to the left.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon the first solution of egreg, one could also center the underline:

```
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\mkern3mu\underline{\mkern-3mu #1\mkern-3mu}\mkern3mu}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the reason is clear: the letters are italic, and "stick out" to the right.  This is a quick hack, working only (or mainly) for letters (and not very robust: it assumes that the same font (or font with same widths, to be precise) is used for text and math):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\narrowunderline}[1]{\mathrlap{\underline{\vphantom{#1}\hphantom{\textup{#1}}}}#1}

\begin{document}
$U\in[\narrowunderline{U},\bar{U}]$

$f\in[\narrowunderline{f},\bar{f}]$
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it's neither elegant, nor gives beautiful results - but it's better than the default.

Comment: I did not even think about the reason, but yeah, you are right on the italic thing.

Comment: More robustness and adjustment: 
`\newcommand{\narrowunderline}[2][1]{\mathrlap{underline{\phantom{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#2}\mkern-#1mu}}}}#2\mkern#1mu}`
(I hoped I managed to copy it correctly from my internet-less work machine)

Comment: @Rasmus, make this into an answer!  (After adding the missing backslash;).)

Comment: I tried to edit it, but the 5 min rule caught me :)  I am reluctant as it seems to change the "kerneling" of letters (as it used that mathrm{.} version).  Thus, it might be better to use the vphantom(.)/hphantom(.) functions.  I'd have to check more...