# Accents package incompatible with bm?

Tags: math-mode, errors, incompatibility, bold, accents

Reading [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s answer to [Decrease length of underline in math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49324/decrease-length-of-underline-in-math), I wanted to use the [`accents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accents) package for lower bars in math mode.

It seem however that the package is incompatible with the [`bm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) package. When I add `\usepackage{accents}` to my preamble, even without using any commands related to the package, I get error messages for all my uses of `\bm`.

```
Missing number, treated as zero ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Parameters must be numbered consecutively ...s when only one specific $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing number, treated as zero ... \leq \left| \sum_{a_i \in \bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted ... \leq \left| \sum_{a_i \in \bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted ... \leq \left| \sum_{a_i \in \bm{\tilde{a}}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ... \leq \left| \sum_{a_i \in \bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted ... \leq \left| \sum_{a_i \in \bm{\tilde{a}}

Parameters must be numbered consecutively ... \leq \left| \sum_{a_i \in \bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing number, treated as zero for any $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted for any $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted for any $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup for any $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted for any $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Parameters must be numbered consecutively for any $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing number, treated as zero ...he case in particular for $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted ...he case in particular for $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing } inserted ...he case in particular for $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ...he case in particular for $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Missing control sequence inserted ...he case in particular for $\bm{\tilde{a}}

Parameters must be numbered consecutively ...he case in particular for $\bm{\tilde{a}}
```

Is there a way to make both packages compatible?

Comment: Minimal example please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `$\bm{\tilde{a}}$`, use `$\tilde{\bm{a}}$`.

OR

Use `$\bm{{\tilde{a}}}$`,  an extra grouping inside `\bm{{...}}`.

Comment: Great, I tried the first solution you proposed and it works! Could you add a word of explanation about why the order or extra grouping matters?

Comment: I think: `\bm` command will expand its argument and spilt everything inside it, causing the error. The grouping here will remove the error.