# Underlined math operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Is there a "best" way to define an underlined math operator? Right now, I've defined

```
DeclareMathOperator{\uHom}{\underline{Hom}}
```

This works, sort of, but the underline is too long---it tends to merge with subscripts, e.g. `$\uHom_R$`:

[image: \uHom_R]

Comment: 1) You're aware that `\hom` is a command in amsmath, right? 2) I fail to see how this question differs from the one at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49324/34551 : can't your find your answer there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a slightly different version: I apply the shortening on both sides, for symmetry.

The shorthening depends on the value given to the parameter `\uHomskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmuskip\uHomskip
\DeclareMathOperator{\uHom}{%
  \mkern\uHomskip
  \underline{\mkern-\uHomskip Hom\mkern-\uHomskip}
  \mkern\uHomskip
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \begingroup\uHomskip=#1mu\relax
  \makebox[2em][l]{#1:}$\uHom_R$
  \endgroup\par
}

\test{0} \test{0.5} \test{1} \test{1.5} \test{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When you decide for the amount you want, just set it in the preamble, for instance

```
\newmuskip\uHomskip \setlength{\uHomskip}{1.5mu}
\DeclareMathOperator{\uHom}{%
  \mkern\uHomskip
  \underline{\mkern-\uHomskip Hom\mkern-\uHomskip}
  \mkern\uHomskip
}
```

The advantage of using `mu` units is that they automatically scale in subscripts/superscripts.

If you don't want the shortening at the left, just remove the relevant kerns:

```
\newmuskip\uHomskip \setlength{\uHomskip}{1.5mu}
\DeclareMathOperator{\uHom}{%
  \underline{Hom\mkern-\uHomskip}
  \mkern\uHomskip
}
```

Comment: What exactly _are_ mu units?

Comment: @AviSteiner 1mu is the 18th part of a quad in the math symbol font for the current math style, so it is particularly apt for math spacing. Such units can only be used in math mode, passed to `\mkern` or `\mskip`.

Answer (score 8):

You can add/remove small spaces before and in the underlined material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\uHom}{\,\underline{\!Hom\!}\,}
\begin{document}
$\uHom_R$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

this answer is much like steven's, but is a little more reserved about the sizes of the "small spaces".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\uHom}{\underline{Hom\kern-.05em}\kern.1em}
\begin{document}
$\uHom_R$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Why not `\mkern1mu\underline{\mkern-1mu Hom\mkern-1mu}\mkern1mu`?

Comment: @egreg -- a reasonable question.  since `\Hom` isn't already defined (although `\hom` is, by `amsopn`, i defined it anew, and `mu` units were rejected with my first try.  possibly a different problem, but i didn't pursue the matter.  i like your symmetry better anyhow.